# Получение списка артефактов с версиями из Nexus через Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, nexus

Каким образом можно получить список версий артефакта из локального Nexus репозитория через Jenkins Pipeline.

Были попытки получения списка при помощи плагина Repository Connector, однако он так и не увидел Nexus.

Есть еще плагин, который только показывает список артефактов по указанным параметрам, однако и данный вариант не подходит.

Comment: Какой тип репозитория и какая версия нексуса (2/3)? Например, для nexus3 и репозитория hosted_npm можно получить через API: `http://<nexus-server>/repository/hosted_npm/<component-name>` - отдаёт красивый JSON, который содержит версии. Получать его можно при помощи HTTP Request Plugin и парсить при помощи `readJSON` из Pipeline Utility Steps.